# How to validate user input contains server code at server side using c#

Tags: json, validation, input, deserialization

I have a search box which allows some of special characters (+,=,#.',") to type and search, here i need to validate user input contains any server codes like 
''+System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe","whoami")+'';)..

Use case details:
A wcf service get input as json data which need to validate before deserialize to avoid creating object when deserialize.I have added custom validation attribue with service contract using IParameterInspector. here when validate the each input fields in beforecall event i would check one field asany of server code or not.
XXS attack-Causes:
Un-sanitized Serialized JSON Data leads to Application Denial of Service (DoS)
solution:
The server must validate and filter the data in the JSON request before it de-serializes it.

Can anyone tell me how to disallow server code by adding validation for input fields?

Comment: Perhaps you should redesign the code so that you aren't vulnerable to injection attacks, rather than trying to filter out certain inputs?

Answer (score 0):

If checking the user input right after the user hits enter is not possible you could add a Message Inspector on the client and/or service side which checks the Message before the request is processed on the server.

More details on the official site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/how-to-inspect-and-modify-messages-on-the-service

**EDIT**
You could specify an array with symbols that are not allowed and only process the rquest if the index is , e.g.

```
if(input.IndexOfAny(new char[] { '+', '!', '\\', '&' })==-1)
 { 
      ... 
 }
```

You can also specify a List of strings with words or just symbols that are not allowed
i.e.

```
List<string> words = new List<string>();
words.Add("WhoAmI");
words.Add("&");
bool badWordDetected = words.Any(w => input.Contains(w));
```

I would also recommend to convert the input to upper or lower case so that the check can be case invariant.

Comment: @Drahcir- I have implemented input validation for WCF as followed bt MSDN  - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647875.aspx . Here my doubt is How to check the user input has some server codes or not. I shared Eg: TextSearch = 
 "+System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe","whoami")+''  , can u share some idea on this.

Comment: @Drahcir- Tanks for your effort.. I have done to restrict profanity already. My requirement is sanitize the input such as htmlencode for input by the same way need to encode/sanitize the server code/language. It is not possible to all lakh of .net keywords to keep in list and verify. is there any way to parse/encode/sanitize input  against the server code.